# ContextLoaderListener problem while spring is loading up

Tags: java, spring

When my spring is loading up, it says `applicationContext.xml` is not found in the classpath by throwing `FileNotFoundException` as can be seen below. Please help me resolve this problem.

my `web.xml` content is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The exception being thrown is as follows,

> SEVERE: Exception sending context
>   initialized event to listener instance
>   of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from
>   class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested
>   exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]
>   cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]
>   cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:297)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:889)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>   Nov 12, 2009 4:02:09 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log

When I don't want any files to be named `applicationContext.xml`, why it has to look for it? as it has been clearly stated in `web.xml`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was due to a simple problem in tomcat.

Long back I was working on a project which was not deleted from tomcat webapp folder. That was spring project too.

I figured it out by commenting out all in web.xml in the current project I am working on. When I did so, it was still trying to load spring container. That's when I opened tomcat manager web application and squinted for the application that wasn't bootstrapped.

I found an application that was not bootstrapped in tomcat manager web application, then I deleted that application, now my application started working like charm...

Answer (score 4):

You've actually configured two different Spring bootstrap loaders - ContextConfigListener will attempt to load a context file (whose name defaults to `applicationContext.xml`), and then DispatcherServlet will be started second and attempt to load your `/WEB-INF/web-spring-context.xml` (DispatcherServlet will load this context as a child of the first).

If you don't need two contexts to load (or to have a parent and child context), you can remove the ContextConfigListener and only use DispatcherServlet.

**update**: What version of Spring are you using? The line numbers in your stacktrace do not match up with the source of org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader that I have for Spring 2.5.6. Are you sure you are using the same version of spring-core and spring-webmvc?

Comment: -1 The `ContextLoaderListener` uses (or should be using) the `contextConfigLocation` that's been specified as a `<context-param>`, in this case `/WEB-INF/Context.xml`. The two-context configuration is deliberate here.

Comment: The `contextConfigLocation` *is* specified as a `context-param`, it's right at the top of the file. It's also specified as an `init-param` to the servlet.

Comment: skaffman is correct - I missed that when I originally read it - however I'm wondering now if unknown has the correct Spring version

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I missed that.  For some reason I thought context params were specified after listeners, so I was just ignoring the top of the file.

Comment: I am using spring version 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Context.xml trying to do an import of applicationContext.xml from the classpath?  The code would look like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>
```

Based on the stacktrace, it's trying to load that file from the classpath (see the 2nd to last entry).  I just tried on my machine and if it can't find the root context file the 2nd line of the trace is `ServletContextResource.getInputStream`, so it's reading Context.xml.

Comment: Context.xml has only one bean defined 'ArrayList' that too is for test purpose.